# Is it possible to make cross (+) dots?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

Is it possible in latex to do crossed dots?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,automata}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=north east,fill=white,minimum width=1.4cm,minimum height=7mm}]
\matrix (mA) [draw,matrix of math nodes]
{
(w_{3,1,1}) & (w_{3,2,1}) & (\hdots) & (w_{3,J,1}) \\
(w_{3,1,2}) & (w_{3,2,2}) & (\hdots) & (w_{3,J,2}) \\
(\vdots)    & (\vdots)    & (\hdots)    & (\vdots) \\
(w_{3,1,F}) & (w_{3,2,F}) & (\hdots) & (w_{3,J,F}) \\
};
\matrix (mB) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mA.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(w_{2,1,1}) & (w_{2,2,1}) & (\hdots) & (w_{2,J,1}) \\
(w_{2,1,2}) & (w_{2,2,2}) & (\hdots) & (w_{2,J,2}) \\
(\vdots)    & (\vdots)    & (\hdots)    & (\vdots) \\
(w_{2,1,F}) & (w_{2,2,F}) & (\hdots) & (w_{2,J,F}) \\
};

\matrix (mC) [draw,matrix of math nodes] at ($(mB.south west)+(1.5,0.7)$)
{
(w_{1,1,1}) & (w_{1,2,1}) & (\hdots) & (w_{1,J,1}) \\
(w_{1,1,2}) & (w_{1,2,2}) & (\hdots) & (w_{1,J,2}) \\
(\vdots)    & (\vdots)    & (\hdots)    & (\vdots) \\
(w_{1,1,F}) & (w_{1,2,F}) & (\hdots) & (w_{1,J,F}) \\
};


\draw[dashed](mA.north east)--(mC.north east);
\draw[dashed](mA.north west)--(mC.north west);
\draw[dashed](mA.south east)--(mC.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I made this 3d matrix in latex, and want one of the column enties to both have vertical and horizontal dots, to indicate that it continues, in both directions.

[image]

It does not look like the dots command has such an option?

Comment: Why not just use `\ddots`? See [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: Well.. `\ddots` is a possibility, but could cause confusion for the target audition..

Comment: Not sure to see what you want. Like `+` sign, but dotted?

Comment: @Bernard yes.. a dotted version of `+`

Comment: If \ddots isn't appropriate, leave it blank.  And what is with the ()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what sort of alignment you desire, or the numbers of dots, so I give several possibilities.  In all cases, they are superpositions of `\dots` and `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$a\stackengine{4pt}{\vdots}{\dots}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}$

$a\stackengine{-4pt}{\dots}{\vdots}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}$

$a\stackengine{0pt}{\stackengine{0pt}{\kern9pt\dots}{\dots\kern9pt}{O}{c}{F}
{F}{L}}{\stackengine{-8pt}{\vdots}{\vdots}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}$
\end{document}
```

[image]